# Passing an array from javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have a number of check boxes on my JSP page. I need to pass ids of all the check boxes to my servlet so that i can perform some database operations. I thought that i can create an array in my javascript function placed in a different .js file which would store these ids and then pass the array to my servlet.
But i m not able to figure out how to apply this concept.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about what you have tried so far? If possible, post a small code sample. The answer will depend, among other things, on whether your checkbox values are to be submitted as part of a form or are being passed via an AJAX call, so be sure to address that.

Comment: i havn't really worked on this problem in my project. But i have used ajax calls in rest of the functions. i am confused about this. what should i pass on as data in the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem is normally approached with

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="4">
```

And then

```
String values[]=req.getParameterValues("foo");
```

Which gives you an array of all the checked values.

Comment: Wat do i pass as data in my request from the ajax function in js.

Comment: You just have multiple key/value pairs in the data with the same key name.

Comment: Can u tell me the code to be used in ajax call.
I m a beginner.

Comment: Writing a complete guide on how to build an Ajax request is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks... i did it this way only...
and sorry for asking the code.